# SmartView Connection

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong on this coding? If I change the (APPName to "itmsales") and (DBName to "item")  and (change the QACommonName in the HypConnect to itmsales), I can connect.  But if I change the APPname, DBName and HypConnect to "daily_05" nothing happens.
If I change HypConnect to QACommonName which is "My Connection" I get a connection Error?

```
Declare Function HypConnect Lib "HsAddin" (
    ByVal vtSheetName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtUserName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtPassword As Variant, 
    ByVal vtFriendlyName As Variant
) As Long

Declare Function HypCreateConnection Lib "HsAddin" (
    ByVal vtSheetName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtUserName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtPassword As Variant, 
    ByVal vtProvider As Variant, 
    ByVal vtProviderURL As Variant, 
    ByVal vtServerName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtApplicationName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtDatabaseName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtFriendlyName As Variant, 
    ByVal vtDescription As Variant) As Long

Sub Example_HypCreateConnection()
    username = "SOME USER"
    password = "SOME PASSWORD"
    Provider = "SOME PROFICER"
    QAProvURL = "http://SOMEDOMAIN:19000/aps/SmartView"
    QAServer = "QASERVER-NAME"
    AppName = "daily_05"
    DBName = "daily_05"
    QACommonName = "My Connection"
    QADescription = "Analylic Provider Services"

    Y = HypCreateConnection(Empty, username, password, Provider, QAProvURL, QAServer, AppName, DBName, QACommonName, QADescription)

    X = HypConnect(Empty, username, password, QACommonName)
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not your *real* password, right?

Comment: Removed all personal info (user, password, url, ...).  Keep it safe and do NOT post personal data!